# vue.js: When implementing the "Simple State Management from Scratch" approach, how to pass on/access the store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This may be a really dumb question, but after reading the [state management documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) of vue.js, i'd like to play around with the store pattern.

I noticed that the `store.state` is shared among the two apps in the example. But how would i now call the `setMessageAction` method of the store from within a component? Shouldn't the store be somehow injected into/registered with the vue instance in order to be accessible via `this` from within a component or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

You should declare your store in your component declaration as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch)

```
document.js


var store = {
    debug: true,
    state: {
          message: 'Hello!'
         },
    setMessageAction (newValue) {
        if (this.debug) console.log('setMessageAction triggered with', newValue)
        this.state.message = newValue
    },

    clearMessageAction () {
        if (this.debug) console.log('clearMessageAction triggered')
        this.state.message = ''
    }
 }



var vmA = new Vue({
   data: {
    privateState: {},

    <!-- HERE YOU ARE PASSING THE STATE -->
    sharedState: store.state
    }
  })
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But i cannot find anything about that in the official docs? Do you have any link at hand, which lists the available key-values understood by the Vue-Constructor?

Comment: Yes, it described as I do here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/#the-simplest-store

Comment: Well, but thats with vuex as a store-backend. My confusion is: The official vue documentation gives you the hint, that you could get away with a simple store pattern instead of going full blown with vuex. So without vuex, your example is just not working, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncpetfL1/2/
`this.$store` is undefined in line 6 of the javascript.

Comment: Ah right sorry. I didn't see what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Ahh,ok. Now I see. It was hidden in plain sight. :D. The keys `privateState` and `sharedState` are not special to vue. They are just "my" convention for this app. And can be accessed via `this.$root.sharedData` and `this.$root.privateData`.